# Backspace button on javascript calculator doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html

The backspace button on my javascript calculator doesn't work(doesn't work remove 1 digit from the screen's length.

JavaScript

```
var screen = document.getElementById("screen");
var backspacebtn = document.getElementById("backspacebtn");
backspacebtn.onclick = () => (screen.length -= 1);
```

HTML

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="10px" cellspacing="30px;">
  <tr>
    <td><input style="width: 99%;background-color:transparent;font-size:60px;text-align:center" id="screen"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><button style="color: red;" id="resetbtn">C</button> <button id="backspacebtn" style="padding-top:10px;color:red">⬅</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`screen.length` just return a value of the length of element (and it also undefined because there's no length in the element), if you want to change the text of input, use `screen.value` that return the input value and also you can set it with `=`

```
screen.value = screen.value.substring(0, screen.value.length - 1);
```